# USB Wifi Dongle changes MAC Address on every boot - How to prevent this?

Tags: networking, 20.04, network-manager, netplan, arm

Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS runs on an Odroid C4 development board.

WiFi works fine with an USB dongle with RTL8811AU chip, but the MAC address is different after each boot. How can I ensure that the MAC address always remains the same, so that I can always assign the same IP address via DHCP?

Command-line system only, no desktop.

Dongle is:

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:a811 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8811AU 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WLAN Adapter
```

Kernel is:

```
Linux odroid 4.9.241-65 #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Dec 23 14:19:21 UTC 2020 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used to have a lan USB adapter and used to do something like this. Try in /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf

```
[connection]
ethernet.cloned-mac-address=NEWMAC
```

and then restart network manager

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Comment: That actually worked :)